# Creating a file and writing to it

Tags: java

I created a file named 'test.txt' and then took input from the user to write the input to the file. Everything runs fine. The program doesn't show any error at all. The file is created and the program takes input from the user but when I checked the content of the file, it was empty. Can anyone figure out what is wrong with my code? The code is as follows.

```
package InputOutput;

import java.io.*;

public class CharacterFileReaderAndFileWriter{

private BufferedReader br = null;
private BufferedWriter bw = null;
private PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);

public File createFile() throws IOException{
    File f = new File("test.txt");
    return f;
}

public void writeToFile() throws IOException{
    try{
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(createFile()));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    //take input from the console (user)
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s;

    pw.println("Please enter something");
    pw.println("To stop the program, enter 'stop'");

    do{
        s = br.readLine();
        if(s.compareTo("stop")==0)
            break;
        s+= "\r\n";//adding an new line to the string s         
        bw.write(s);            
    }
    while(s.compareTo("stop")!=0);

    br.close();
    bw.close();

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    CharacterFileReaderAndFileWriter cfr = new CharacterFileReaderAndFileWriter();
    cfr.writeToFile();
}
```

}

Comment: I tried your code. It worked fine for me without any change. The output file contained the text I entered. Are you not getting the file contents under specific conditions?

Comment: It's working now. The file wasn't created in the same folder as the source code file was in. So I specified the full path. Thanks for you time guys. Really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @krishnakumarp yeah, the IDE didn't actually create the file for me in the directory with just the file name. So I entered full path while creating the file. It is working fine now

Comment: The default output folder would be the folder from which you invoked the program. In case you ran from IDE like eclipse, the file would be put in the project's root folder.

Comment: @krishnakumarp 'E:\Programming\Class files\practice\src\InputOutput'-> This is where my java source code is. Without specifying the output folder, will Eclipse create the file in the same folder or somewhere else?

Comment: By default, it should create the output file in 'E:\Programming\Class files\practice' folder

Comment: @Nikhar i didn't know i have to accept the answer.... thanx for that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most example programs show that you have to call`.flush()` on your `BufferedWriter` before the `.close()`. This should not be required, `.close()` should call `.flush()` automatically, but it doesn't hurt. Also you should call all the `Stream`/`Writer` objects `.close()` methods in reverse order as well, again correctly written classes should call `.close()` on all the object they wrap, but it doesn't hurt to do it anyway.

Other things that might catch you out later:

```
if(s.compareTo("stop")==0)
```

should be

```
if ("stop".equalsIgnoreCase(s))
```

it is more efficient, eliminates the possibility of a `NullPointerException` on `s`, handles any case of *stop* and most importantly more idiomatic Java than using `.compareTo()`

```
    s+= "\r\n";//adding an new line to the string s         
    bw.write(s);
```

should be

```
    bw.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));        
    bw.write(s);
```

The `s+=` creates intermediate objects and garbage that needs to be collected. Hard coding line endings is bad as well.

Comment: Isn't close called at the end of the writeToFile() method?

Comment: I did call .close() on BufferedWriter. It is at the end of the method writeToFile().

Comment: Right, which is why I don't understand this (or wakaka's) answer.

Answer (score -2):

You need close the outputstream.
file.close();